# CSS3 linear gradient + rgba, not so true transparency

Tags: css, transparency, gradient, linear-gradients

I have a page setup that looks similar to this:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--- ... content ... -->
    </div>
</body>
```

The body has a background color and a tiling image that adds some noise and grain to the background. On top of that, #wrapper has a linear gradient as background that goes from rgba(0,0,0,.3) to rgba(0,0,0,0) and the gradient expands over 24 pixels at the top of the div, which is at the top of the page --- to add a shadow.

My problem is, that the color that the background of #wrapper holds after the 24 pixel gradient is done, is not true transparency, even though the end color of the gradient has an alpha value of zero. What this leaves me with, is a not true transparent background on #wrapper, that leaves a visible "split-line" on the body-background at the spot where #wrapper stops.

How do I get the gradient to go in to full transparency? I would guess an alpha value of zero would do this. Also, using the `transparent` keyword doesn't solve it either.

**Update**

I have added pictures to show the problem. The first picture is the actual look, and the second significantly shows where the line is, because it's there, though very unclear on the first picture.

[image: actual look]
[image]

As you can see, the gradient doesn't go in to true transparency. Not when the to-color is specified as `rgba(0,0,0,0)` or `transparent`.

-- Chris Buchholz

Comment: Can you show us your css code for wrapper? This might seem obvious, but did you add a box-shadow to #wrapper?

Comment: and uploading a screenshot of what's happening is very handy too. Also what browser/device?

Comment: It would help if you provided the CSS code for your gradient, a rendering of what happens and a mockup of what you want to happen.

Comment: Why don't you just add a box-shadow? It sounds like that is what you really want anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing it in a webkit browser (chrome/safari), firefox, IE or Opera? As they all treat gradients differently.

I don't fully understand though I believe you should consider using CSS gradient generators online, most of them use solid colors, just replace the hex decimal with the new RGBA().

That's the best way to learn how you're going wrong.

Other then that If you've defined opacity on the wrapper div that could be the Issue.

That's the best I can do

Comment: I'm testing in both Safari, Google Chrome and Firefox. Problem is the same. I need a shadow in the top of the page that goes from black to transparent. The body of the page has a background-image, so I need the gradient (the shadow) to go transparent and not just end in a color. When using `transparent` or RGBA, I'm not getting true transparency. I have added pictures to the post, to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply your CSS code. That will help spot the problem better. But one of possible issue is probably the stacking of CSS properties.

```
#wrapper {
  background: rgb(174,188,191);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(174,188,191,1) 0%,rgba(110,119,116,1) 50%,rgba(10,14,10,1) 51%,rgba(10,8,9,1) 100%);
}
```

[Sample expected](http://jsfiddle.net/SedQ3/5/)

```
#wrapper {
  background: rgb(174,188,191);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(174,188,191,1) 0%,rgba(110,119,116,1) 50%,rgba(10,14,10,1) 51%,rgba(10,8,9,1) 100%);
  background: #111; /*Overrides the above properties*/
}
```

You overrode the first with another background property, maybe somewhere in your CSS with higher priority, causing your transparency overriden:

[Sample overriden](http://jsfiddle.net/7MkUz/)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same kind of problem... and realized it was because I was saving the images as JPGs.  You need something that supports transparency.